# Fedora 14 for beginner

Tags: linux, website, ftp, fedora-14

I just installed Fedora 14 on a really old box I used Windows and Mac OS X a lot. I want to use Linux now. Does anyone know some good resources for beginner Linux users? I want to learn to build an FTP Server and I want to get really familiar with the command lines.

Answer (score 2):

As usual, let the war begin: [Ubuntu](http://www.ubuntu.com/) might be easier than Fedora; there are many Ubuntu beginners around, and so there is huge amount of good tutorials, forums and forum posts. There is also excellent [Ask Ubuntu Stack Exchange site](https://askubuntu.com/). You can use Fedora too, there is nothing wrong with that.

There isn't many distribution specific guides for beginners. List of some useful resources:

- http://www.linux.ie/newusers/beginners-linux-guide/
- http://beginnerlinuxtutorial.com/
- Linux for Dummies (physical book)
- Linux Administration: A Beginner's Guide (physical book)

Comment: I love the "for Dummies" series :)

Answer (score 0):

Here are some links that are related to your question:

[FedoraProject Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/Fedora_Project_Wiki). You can find full documentation here, as well as explanations of the packaging, bug fixes, and just anything in general.

For commands used in bash, this is useful:

[bash commands - Linux MAN Pages](http://ss64.com/bash/)

For setting up an FTP, try this HOWTO:

[Quick HOWTO : Ch15 : Linux FTP Server Setup](http://www.linuxhomenetworking.com/wiki/index.php/Quick_HOWTO_:_Ch15_:_Linux_FTP_Server_Setup)

Google will also be your best friend. Since Fedora is a Linux distribution, anything made for Linux will work on it, and not just Fedora alone. So any errors you find can usually be Google'd with an answer.

The best way to get used to Linux is just to try it. If you mess up, things are usually reversible.

There is also a book available here:

[Fedora Bible 2011 Edition: Featuring Fedora Linux 14](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/047094496X)